# How to create a local server for website in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, web

I am trying to make a website using local server in visual studio 2010. I posted before about the errors that I got during debugging.

Now I just want to make sure that I am doing the correct thing to create a local SQL server.
I created a .mdf database in the App_code, configured the web.config and created a table for the .mdf database. Is that just what I need to do to create a local server?

thanks

Comment: No. All you've done is create the database, you still need SQL Server installed for the database to attach to.

Comment: oh ok. I installed the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. Do I need to attach the database manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SQL Server installed on the machine, and you have the database in your App_Data directory then you can just connect it in the connection string:

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf; Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```